# Override Request Content-Type Header and Derive Type from URL

Tags: rest, http-headers, content-type

I have a question regarding a REST API's HTTP compliance.  Is it ever advisable to override / ignore the "*Content-Type*" header in a request body when designing a REST API interface and instead derive the type of content from information provided in the URL?

For example, is there a reason to allow the following example:

```
POST /url.xml
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
...
</xml>
```

In this workflow the content-type is determined by the ".xml" extension on the URL, which is non-standard.  In general it is poor practice to rely on non-standards in lieu of standards.  However, some REST API clients will automatically add a default content-type if the developer does not specify one.

Is there ever a reason to break away from the standard and override the content-type in a request entity?  Wouldn't this break interoperability on the web?

Comment: I'd also be interested to find out what people think the "right" behavior should be if you set a Content-Type header that disagreed with the URL extension?  Should the Content-Type just win, and then the REST API would process the request based on that Content-Type.